# Expression.Lambda getter function compile

Tags: c#

#### code:

```
static Func<T,object> CompileGetValueExpression<T>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    var instance = Expression.Parameter(propertyInfo.DeclaringType, "i");
    var property = Expression.Property(instance, propertyInfo);
    var convert = Expression.TypeAs(property, typeof(object));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T,object>>(convert, instance).Compile();
}
```

#### e.g

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new Test{prop1 = 1};
    var type = data.GetType();
    var prop = type.GetProperties().First();
    var function = CompileGetValueExpression<Test>(prop);
    var result = function(data); //result:1
}

class Test{
    public int prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

#### question

Is this expression function exactly equal to below method?

```
object GetterFunction(Test i) => i.prop1 as object;
```

Comment: `CompileGetValueExpression` returns a `string`, `prop1` is an `int` and `GetterFunction` casts to `object` for some reason. So... no?

Comment: thanks @kalimag i fixed it. it's object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they are. One evidence is if you dump expression created in `CompileGetValueExpression` as string, it outputs `i => (i.prop1 As Object)`.

Try to modify the last line of `CompileGetValueExpression`

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(convert, instance).ToString();
```